# Как убрать перевод строки при вызове print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример:

```
a = int(input("Введите длину линии: "))

def line(a):
    for i in range(a):
        print("—")

print(line(a))
```

Всё работает без ошибок, вот только он выводит "—" его по одной на одну строку, а мне надо чтобы он вывел их всех в одну строку. Не знаете как это сделать?

Comment: выберите лучший ответ, раз вам помогли. так принято на  StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы выводите результат функции через `print`, то в самой функции не делайте `print`, а только формируйте строку, и возвращайте ее через `return`:

```
a = int(input("Введите длину линии: "))


def line(a):
    s = ''

    for i in range(a):
        s += '-'

    return s


print(line(a))
```

Можно функцию упростить до двух строк:

```
def line(a):
    return '-' * a
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

В Python 3 вы можете использовать параметр `end=` функции `print`:

```
print("—", end="")
```

Подсмотрено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/6766879)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
def line(a):
    print('-' * a)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Hello, ", end='')
print("world!")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```py
print("—", end="", flush=True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]